# JPanel methods stop working after a code snippet is run

Tags: java, swing

I am implementing a version of the card game Set. I have a `JPanel` object called `CardPanel` which displays all the cards along with appropriate listeners.

```
public class CardPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener {
    public CardPanel() {
        setLayout(gridLayout);

        placeCards(N);
        chatBoxText = new JTextArea(5, 30);
    }

    public void placeCards(int numCards) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numCards; i++) {
            Card card = deck.distributeCard();
            String cardImageName = card.getImageName();

            JLabel jLabel = makeImage(cardImageName);
            cardSet.add(new GraphicCard(card, jLabel));

            add(jLabel);
            jLabel.addMouseListener(this);
        }

        if (GameLogic.noSetsOnBoard(cardSet)) {
            gridLayout.setRows(gridLayout.getRows() + 1);
            placeCards(3);
        }
    }

    public void updateCard(Integer location) {
        Card card = deck.distributeCard();
        String cardImageName = card.getImageName();

        JLabel jLabel = makeImage(cardImageName);
        cardSet.set(location, new GraphicCard(card, jLabel));

        jLabel.addMouseListener(this);
    }

    public void mouseListener...
}
```

A GraphicCard object is just a joint of a Card as defined in Set and a JLabel which contains the image of that card. When I initially populate the deck everything works fine. All the cards are displayed.

When a Set is submitted, the game is multiplayer, so the Client sends the necessary information to the Server which then broadcasts that update to all the Clients. The update method that is run is the following:

```
public void correctSetUpdate(ArrayList<Integer> submittedTriplet, Player player) {
    boolean removeRow = true;

    cardPanel.removeAll();
    cardPanel.add(cardSet.get(0).getJLabel());

    for (int cardLocation : submittedTriplet) {
        if (cardSet.size() > N) {
            cardSet.remove(cardLocation);
            if (removeRow) {
                gridLayout.setRows(gridLayout.getRows() - 1);
                removeRow = false;
            }
        } else {
            if (deck.deckSize() != 0) {
                cardPanel.updateCard(cardLocation);
            }
        }
    }

    for (GraphicCard card: cardSet) {
        cardPanel.add(card.getJLabel());
    }
}
```

The `cardSet` object is an `ArrayList` of all `GraphicCard` currently on the board. Now here is the weird part. Where you see `cardPanel.removeAll()` and then I add something the next line, this works fine (obviously it's not the functionality that I want). I submit a set, it goes through the Server and now all of the boards have just that first card from `cardSet`. If I remove that line and run the `for` loop that follows, none of the `cardPanel` methods work anymore. If I invoke `removeAll()` after the for loop nothing happens, and if I try adding, nothing happens, at least not visually. What am I missing in this for loop that is causing the behavior of `cardPanel` methods to behave so strange after this loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add (or remove) components from a visible GUI the basic code is:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

The revalidate() invokes the layout manager and the repaint() makes sure the components are painted at their proper size/location.

Comment: Any idea why it worked without this additional code before the for loop?

Comment: @mike, No, I don't understand you verbal description of the problem and the code you posted is not executable and I don't have time to look at the code in detail. I'm just giving you the proper way to code your application.

Comment: This works, sorry if I was unclear. Basically before the loop, the panel was updating correctly without the `panel.revalidate()` and `panel.repaint()`. After the loop was executed, those two lines became absolutely necessary.